# Does C++ compiler optimize out #includes that are not used?

Tags: c++, optimization, include, c-preprocessor

When building a growing library of classes/functions, I've commonly seen a sort of "umbrella" header file that #includes all the common header files of a project.  For example:

```
dsp.h
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
...
#include "filex.h"
```

Sometimes I might need everything, but other times maybe only a selection of features/options.  If #include dsp.h, but don't use anything from file2.h for example, does the compiler know? Is it possible for it to optimize it out in the build?

Otherwise, my solution is to wrap optional code inside preprocessor directives and then define what I need. Perhaps this is a safer, more efficient solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about code optimization or optimization of build time?

Unnecessary, unused headers will not change the code that is being generated, so there is no question of optimization here.

However, it will increase build time. This is not optimized by build tools. If you are looking to optimize build time, look at the book **Large Scale C++ Software Design** by **John Lakos**.

Comment: I'm talking about code optimization, not build time. Basically, if a header file is included that isn't used, will it still be included in the built executable, thus increasing code size?

Comment: @user93353 You can't make that determination without knowing the code of the header file.

Comment: @NikosC. Do you have an example where a header is unused, but still increases the code size?

Comment: @user93353 A typical class header. All data/code the class needs is obviously saved into the binary. A simple test is compiling an trivial program with just an empty main() function. On my system, the created object file is 752 bytes big. Adding just this one include: `#include <iostream>` will result in an object file that's 992 bytes big. All debug symbols are stripped. Most header files will have this effect.

Comment: @NikosC. I tried this is on Visual Studio 2010. My exe size doesn't change between a program with just an empty `main` & one with also a `#include <iostream>`. It remains the same. I think the linker should be smart enough to discard all unused stuff. Sure the standard says nothing about this, but any sophisticated linker should be able to do this. Also iostream may be a special case - may be your tools pull in the standard library only when atleast one std library header is included.

Comment: @user93353 Your compiler works different than mine. But you can't extrapolate this to all compilers out there by simply saying "no, it won't increase code size."

Comment: @Nikos C. Ok. I change my statement to "With a reasonably modern, sophisticated linker, it shouldn't increase code size". Also, I don't see why code size should increase. What's your compiler/linker & do you see this with headers other than `iostream`. Can you handcraft a header which will increase code size?

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor doesn't do any optimization. It doesn't know anything about the semantics of your code and thus cannot tell whether you're using anything from a header file or not. So no, `#include` statements are not optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

Since the preprocessor is a separate program (and language) from the C++ compiler, there's no way for the preprocessor to know what is used. So the compiler will receive everything that was in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The include files are are read, and are inserted part of the source code before the compiler really starts generating code.

Yes.  As a general rule, things that are not referenced by the program are not put into the final executable.  It is ok to think of that as being an optimization.  The details will differ depending on the compiler and linker.